# Model instance methods are no longer supported in Sails v1

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I keep getting the error "In the `customToJSON` attribute of model `user`:
Model instance methods are no longer supported in Sails v1.
Please refactor the logic from this instance method into
a static method, model method or helper.". I'm new to node.js and don't know what do to about it.

My User.js

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const Promise = require("bluebird")

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    username: {
      type: "string",
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: "email",
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password:{
      type: "string",
      minLength: 6,
      required: true,
      columnName: "encryptedPassword"
    },  
    customToJSON: function(){
        const obj = this.toObject()
        delete obj.password
    }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, I hope you are enjoying developing with Node and Sails.

Now to solve your issue, I guess you are using a guide or tutorial based off sails v0.12 but like the error message says, instance methods have been removed from Sails and Waterline as of v1.

With that said, the solution is quite an easy one, move your customToJSON method out of the attributes section of your model. This basically allows sails v1 to find it.

So your model will look something like this

```
...
attributes: {
    ...
    ,
    password:{
      type: "string",
      minLength: 6,
      required: true,
      columnName: "encryptedPassword"
    },
},

customToJSON: function() {
    return _.omit(this, ['password']); 
},
...
```

For more info on customToJSON in sails see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson) and for more info on replacing instance methods see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models#?what-about-instance-methods).

Comment: I did the same you suggested above but I am getting the same error